# How can we be certain that the integral represents the exact area under a curve, or could it be possibly slightly different from the calculated value?

Tags: calculus

The main idea of the integral is that to calculate the area under a curve, we divide the area under the curve into small rectangles. If we call the length of these rectangles $\Delta x$, then the smaller $\Delta x$ is, the better approximation of the area under the curve is obtained. The point is that $\Delta x$ cannot be exactly zero, because then the area would be zero! So $\Delta x$ must be very, very close to zero. In fact, no matter how close $\Delta x$ is to zero, we can never get the exact area. But we know that as $\Delta x$ gets closer to zero, the area gets closer to a number like $S$. So we conclude that the exact area value must be $S$. Everything seems logical and correct, but to me it is not. My question is, it is true that the area is getting closer and closer to $S$, but maybe the actual area is not equal to $S$. What is the guarantee that the actual area must be exactly $S$? In fact, we never get the actual area, so how are we sure that the area is exactly equal to $S$? How do you know that, for example, the area is not $S + 1$?

Note: I really like calculus myself, but sometimes some things in calculus don't make sense to me. Furthermore, I am not sure that I have been able to express my question correctly.

Comment: tl;dr. How do you define $S$ if you have no integral?

Comment: @KurtG. While I understand that the limit suggests that the area approaches the value $S$ as $\Delta x$ becomes infinitesimally small, my question aims to address the philosophical aspect of whether we can definitively assert that the area is precisely equal to $S$. In other words, how do we know that, as $\Delta x$ tends towards zero, the area under the curve is exactly $S$ and not $S$ plus some infinitesimally small quantity?

Comment: It's not a question about the mathematical procedures involved in calculus but rather a query about the philosophical underpinnings and the certainty we have about the equality between the limit and the actual value. I'm seeking clarification on the theoretical guarantee that the actual area must be exactly equal to $S$ and not, for instance, $S$ plus some infinitesimally small quantity.

Comment: The integral is not a way to calculate the area under the curve, it is the definition of the area under the curve.

Comment: Ok. Let me put my philosopher's hat on. If we have a non-integrable function how can we talk about the area under its graph before we even consider $\Delta x$?

Comment: This is the fundamental basis of mathematics with limits.  There isn't much we can do or say about it except that either accept limits work or we declare all mathematics as an abstract and unreal mootness. Anyway, you talk of the "actual area", but what is that?  It's certainly nothing that actually exists.  You as if it is S plus (why not minus) some "infinitesimally small quantity" but how can an "infinitesimally small quantity have any practical or non-contradictory meaning? Math *is* a philosophy and it can be what we make it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following will convince you.

The lower $L_{\Delta x}$ and upper $U_{\Delta x}$ Riemann sums are *definitely* a lower and upper bound of the "true" area $A$ under a curve.
$$L_{\Delta x} ≤ A ≤ U_{\Delta x}$$
If both the upper and lower Riemann sums converge to the same area when we let $\Delta x \to 0$
$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} L_{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} U_{\Delta x}$$
this *must* mean that
$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0} L_{\Delta x} =  A = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} U_{\Delta x}$$
a la sandwhich theorem.

Comment: The answer is precise and correct. +1 Now I am convinced!

Comment: At the risk of opening a Pandora's box: It's not always the case that the upper and lower Riemann sums converge to the same limit.  But at least if the function in question is reasonable (meaning Riemann-integrable), then sure, they'll converge to the same limit.

Answer (score 0):

When we say that the area under the curve approaches a number $S$ as $\Delta x$ approaches zero, we're using the concept of a **limit**. The notation for this is:

$$\lim_{{\Delta x} \to 0} A = S$$

where $A$ is the area under the curve. This means that as $\Delta x$ gets arbitrarily close to zero, the area $A$ gets arbitrarily close to $S$.

Now, you're correct that we never actually let $\Delta x$ be exactly zero. But the power of the limit concept is that it allows us to talk about what happens as $\Delta x$ gets "infinitely close" to zero.

In terms of your question about why the area isn't $S + 1$, the answer lies in the definition of a limit. If the area were $S + 1$, then as $\Delta x$ gets closer and closer to zero, the area would get closer and closer to $S + 1$, not $S$. But we've defined the limit as $S$, so by definition, the area cannot be $S + 1$.

This is a subtle point, and it's at the heart of why calculus works. It's also why calculus sometimes seems counterintuitive: it deals with concepts like infinity and infinitesimals that don't have analogs in our everyday experience. But these concepts have been rigorously defined and proven to work over centuries of mathematical thought.

Answer (score 0):

We can get even more rigorous than the other answers. See the following exercise from [Folland's Real Analysis](https://apachepersonal.miun.se/%7Eandrli/Bok.pdf)

50. Suppose $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $f \in L^{+}(X)$. Let
    $$
    G_f=\{(x, y) \in X \times[0, \infty]: y \leq f(x)\} .
    $$

Then $G_f$ is $\mathcal{M} \times \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$-measurable and $\mu \times m\left(G_f\right)=\int f d \mu$; the same is also true if the inequality $y \leq f(x)$ in the definition of $G_f$ is replaced by $y<f(x)$. (To show measurability of $G_f$, note that the map $(x, y) \mapsto f(x)-y$ is the composition of $(x, y) \mapsto(f(x), y)$ and $(z, y) \mapsto z-y$.) This is the definitive statement of the familiar theorem from calculus, "the integral of a function is the area under its graph."

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but a series of comments that will hopefully be clarifying.

(1) If you're working with the real number system (as I assume you are), then there's no such thing as an "infinitesimally small quantity."

(2) As others have suggested, it sounds like your issue is with limits, and not integrals per se.  For example, consider the sequence
$$1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, \ldots, \frac{1}{n}, \ldots$$
Paraphrasing the text in your question: "None of the terms $\frac{1}{n}$ are exactly zero, but nevertheless get close to zero.  In fact, no matter how large $n$ gets, the terms $\frac{1}{n}$ never actually become zero, yet approach a limit $L$."

So, to be clear, the limit of $\frac{1}{n}$ is *not* "infinitesimally close to zero," but simply equal to zero.  In other words, $L = 0$.  Hopefully that much is uncontroversial.  Now, in exactly the same way, the limit of Riemann sums isn't "infinitesimally close to $S$," but is just plain equal to $S$.

(3) Also as others have suggested, there's also the issue of what exactly you mean by "area."  Your post speaks of the area of $S$ as though it has some well-defined mathematical meaning, but of course ideas don't have precise meanings until you give them one.

So, how should we define area?  There are different ways to do it, but the simplest (by far) for the purposes of a calculus course is the tautological one: just define the area of a region under a curve to be the integral of the relevant function.

Of course this approach renders your question a non-issue, and perhaps that feels unsatisfying.  But I should caution that virtually any other approach, to my knowledge, will be far more difficult (at least if one is concerned with rigor and details).  For an illustration of "far more difficult," see the (correct) answer by random_0620

Answer (score 0):

Archimedes came up with a technique for finding the area of a circle called [The Method of Exhaustion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_exhaustion).

It was known how to find the area of regular polygons. It was also known how to inscribe a polygon into a circle or circumscribe one around it. It could also be proven that the area of the circumscribed polygon was always greater than the area of a right triangle with base the circumference of the circle and the height equal to the radius. An inscribed polygon has a smaller are than that triangle. As the number of sides increased, the circumscribed polygon got smaller an the inscribed polygon got bigger, colliding at the actual answer.

This is how calculus works in general. Instead of directly  proving that two quantities are equal, prove indirectly by proving their difference is smaller than any positive quantity and larger than any negative quantity. Proving that justifies their difference is zero, or in other words, they are equal.

The same applies to the area under a curve. You can approximate with  a quantity you know to be larger and a quantity you know to be smaller and prove that adjustments of the approximation makes them match in the long run.